# YAML Powershell Install-Module every time?

Tags: powershell, azure-devops, yaml

I have an pipeline that executes a powershell script. In that script I need to install a module.

```
### INSTALL MODULES AND LOGIN TO POWER ###
Write-Host "### Installing PBI module..." -ForegroundColor Green;
Install-module -Name "MicrosoftPowerBIMgmt" -AllowClobber -Scope CurrentUser -Verbose
```

My questions is: it's possible to install the module just once, without having to install every time the script runs?

Comment: After installing once, use the module with [Import-Module](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/import-module)

Comment: Do you use MS agent or Self-Hosted agent?

Comment: We use MS agent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, from the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/hosted?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#software), we can know that the hosted agents don't have the `MicrosoftPowerBIMgmt` modules installed. So we need to install module.

Secondly, after the pipeline finished, our server will recycle the image of the currently used host agent. And the system will obtain a brand new agent image when you re-run the pipeline. So, this powershell task must be executed in every pipeline to let the environment satisfied your requirements.

You can refer to the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/agents?view=azure-devops&tabs=browser#microsoft-hosted-agents) for this point:

> Each time you run a pipeline, you get a fresh virtual machine. The
> virtual machine is discarded after one use.

If you don not want to install module every time, you can consider to set up a [self-hosted agent](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/agents?view=azure-devops&tabs=browser#install).

Answer (score 0):

The command `Install-Module` installs it in that environment and also has a `-Scope` switch for whether to install for `AllUsers` (Windows) or just for the `CurrentUser` that runs the command. This switch affects the install path of the module and whether it goes in the user profile or in a system location. It defaults to CurrentUser.

The install locations of both are available through the environment variable $env:PSModulePath

Once installed, as Theo points out, you can just call it with `Import-Module` . However, whether this is possible for you depends on the both the user under which you are running the code, whether their profile is persistent and what `-Scope` it was installed for.

Answer (score 0):

As stated in other answers/comments, use `Import-Module` to import a previously installed module. If you want to know if you've already *installed* a module (let's say, the `Az` module for Azure), you can use:

```
$installed = Get-InstalledModule Az

if ($installed) {
  Import-Module Az
} else {
  Install-Module Az -AllowClobber -Scope CurrentUser -Verbose
}
```